# How to search on lastname and firstname with one variable given

Tags: php, mysql

I have first_name and last_name

so this is my current query on PHP

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE CONCAT_WS(first_name, " ", last_name)') LIKE $name.'%'
```

my sample DB:

```
firstname   |   lastname
-------------------------
Joe         |   Smith
Bien        |   Tibor
Brocs       |   Mar
Joe         |   Gold
```

---

this is my Test Result

Test 1: `name = Joe`

```
firstname   |   lastname
-------------------------
Joe         |   Smith
Joe         |   Gold
```

Test 2: `name = Smith`

```
firstname   |   lastname
-------------------------
"No Results Found"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the wildcard `%` on either side of the `$name` variable.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE CONCAT(`first_name`, ' ', `last_name`) LIKE '%".$name."%'";
```

Comment: but what if I search `oe` then it should result non.

Comment: @StormSpirit If you search 'oe' then it will return both the Joe rows, isn't that what you want?

Comment: I think it will not return both joe since It didnt start from the name.

Comment: @StormSpirit It will because of the wildcard character `%`

Comment: I'm not sure if you want "oe" to return the Joe rows or not. If you do not, then you could just use an OR. If you do want "oe" to return Joe rows then this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add the % widlcard on both ends of $name, so your query looks like '%Smith%'

Needless to say you need to consider proper sql sanitization  so consider using something like PDO

Answer (score 0):

Hi Your `CONCAT_WS` syntax is wrong

It should be

```
CONCAT_WS (separator, string1, string2,…)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude results from searching "oe" then you could just use an OR instead:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname = ' . $name .' OR lastname = ' . $name
```

Comment: yeah but when we use full name "Joe Smith", it doesnt result anything.

Answer (score 0):

First create a `FULLTEXT` index on your table:

```
ALTER TABLE `tbl`
ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `full_name` (`firstname`, `lastname`)
```

Then perform a [natural language search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html).

```
SELECT users.*, 
MATCH(users.firstname, users.lastname)
AGAINST (? IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS relevance
FROM users
```

Use a bound parameter to replace that `?` with your *name* string.

Since this search will be performed against an index it will be significantly faster, on large datasets, than wildcard string matching.